# Android dial a phone number programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

How do I `dial a number` programmatically from the Android application? I don't want to make a call, which I know I can do by making an intent: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)`, I just want to take the user to the Android dial prompt, with the number *already* input by passing it through the intent, so that she has the option to call that number herself.

Comment: Again, the link describes how to make a call, not how to dial a number.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: You can provide input number to dail from your activity using this code, you can not provide dial number in answer provided by @user370305

Comment: @fremmedehenvendelser this is a complete snippet as against what user370305 has provided. He mentions adding the the number in the answer but doesn't do so in code.

Comment: @AngelJanniee it may not be working because you have forgot to delare the caLL_PHONE permission in your manifest or you may have forgotten to request for permission at runtime on android 6.0+

Answer (score 10):

Use [`ACTION_DIAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL)

Like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
```

Activity Action: Dial a number as specified by the data. This shows a UI with the number being dialed, allowing the user to explicitly initiate the call.

Answer (score 8):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Don't forget to add the relevant permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I have asked how to *dial* a number, not how to make a call.

Comment: Although off-topic, I'm glad he posted this answer. It was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This code will make a call without user interaction and will also pick up the default phone dialler

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + url));
    intent.setClassName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

IF you wants the user to choose his dialler remove

```
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster");
```

If you want just to throw the number to the dialler and the user press the call button use this code (I believe thats what you are asking for )

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + url));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Where the url is the phone number 
and dont forget to write the permission in the manifest file .

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Please, see Systematix Infotech's answer.

Comment: what about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was solved by

```
        btn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String q=(t.getText().toString());
            Uri u=Uri.parse("tel:"+q);

            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,u);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will dial your number without mobile phones default calling keypad:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + textView.getText())); 
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone","com.android.phone.OutgoingCallBroadcaster");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```