# Dial number on Android phone from the Java app on PC

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to remotely dial a number on the Android phone from a Java application running on the PC. 
The connection between the PC and phone can be over Bluetooth or WiFi.
Is there a simple way how to do it? If necessary I can develop a separate part which will be running on the Android phone, but there is a limitation that the phone can't be rooted. I would like to avoid using any app available from the Google Play, unless it is opensource.

I'm thinking of a Bluetooth service or a web service running on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think certainly you will need to write code that will run on the phone. The way that comes to mind is to write a socket server on the phone that waits for a client PC to connect and tell it what number do dial, then once it receives this use the normal phone dialer intent (link below). That shouldn't be too difficult.

The trickier part is that if you want to use this is any serious way (ie put it on the play store) you should have some sort of encryption / authentication so that random hackers walking by can't make your phone dial numbers.

To dial a number programatically, see this thread:
[Android dial a phone number programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372561/android-dial-a-phone-number-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. This could work, I'm just thinking whether the socket server will drain the battery more or less than some solution over bluetooth.

Comment: Btw, i do not want to publish it on Google Play, this is to solve a new feature request for the existing system by my customer. There is a system used by more assistants, who need to contact their customers directly from the application, but using their mobile phones. I think I'll solve the pairing security by some PIN number. Another problem is to handle pairing with the correct phone as there  will be more of them on the wifi network. I suppose I will need to register all the phones in another webservice running at the intranet server. But thats the next step,currently I just want to dial...

Comment: Interesting application.

Comment: Interesting application. Additional thoughts: 1) whether you use wifi or Bluetooth connectivity, you will still need a background service to handle incoming requests. Sockets are probably the lowest level / lightest such server layer 2) socket servers in the background are super common, you probably already have hundreds of them running on your phone already. 3) using any standard Bluetooth pairing would make my security fears go away.

Comment: Thanks. And do you recommend using the SocketServer directly? What about some NIO library like AndroidAsync?

Comment: Good question. I always write my socket stuff from scratch, but I'm a bit obsessed with having complete control over how my code works. Using a library would probably be simpler.

Comment: Thank you Mike, i'll try to do some prototype. :)