# Call number when click list view item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a contact list activity but want to add some functionality so that when you click on a contact it will begin calling their phone number. I have tried this code snippet but nothing happens when I tap on a contact:

```
  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + currentContact.getPhone()));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                try{
                    ((Activity) context).startActivity(callIntent);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

All Contact activity code:

```
public class ContactList extends ActionBarActivity {

Spinner spinner, spinnerFilter;
EditText nameTxt, phoneTxt, emailTxt, addressTxt;
ImageView contactImageimgView, btnSort;
List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
ListView contactListView;
//Uri imageUri = null;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Bitmap photoTaken;
String userId;

boolean isReverseEnabledPriority = false, isReverseEnabledName = false;
//ArrayList<Contact> contacts;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);

    SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
    userId = user.get("uid");

    nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    phoneTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
    emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    addressTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    contactImageimgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);
    spinner =  (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerFilter =  (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFilter);
    btnSort =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSort);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Creator");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabCreator);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("add contact");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tabContactList);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("contact list");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    getContacts(ContactList.this);

    btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String filter = spinnerFilter.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(filter.equals("Priority")){

                Collections.sort(Contacts, new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    public int compare(Contact v1, Contact v2) {
                        return v1.getPriorityVal().compareTo(v2.getPriorityVal());
                    }
                });
                if(isReverseEnabledPriority)
                    Collections.reverse(Contacts);
                isReverseEnabledPriority = !isReverseEnabledPriority;
                populateList();

            }else if(filter.equals("Name")){

                Collections.sort(Contacts, new Comparator<Contact>() {
                    public int compare(Contact v1, Contact v2) {
                        return v1.getName().compareTo(v2.getName());
                    }
                });
                if(isReverseEnabledName)
                    Collections.reverse(Contacts);
                isReverseEnabledName = !isReverseEnabledName;
                populateList();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(ContactList.this, "Please selectr a method to sort..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


    final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Contact contact = new Contact(photoTaken, nameTxt.getText().toString(), phoneTxt.getText().toString(), emailTxt.getText().toString(), addressTxt.getText().toString(), spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), userId);
            Contacts.add(contact);
            saveContact(contact, ContactList.this);
        }
    });


    nameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
            addBtn.setEnabled(!nameTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    contactImageimgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);

        }
    });
}

void getContacts(final Context context){
    new Thread(){
        private Handler handler = new Handler();
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Please wait..", false);
                }
            });

            try {
                Contacts = ContactsController.getAllContactsOfUser(userId);

                populateList();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }.start();
}

void saveContact(final Contact contact, final Context context){
    new Thread(){
        private Handler handler = new Handler();
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        boolean result = false;
        int id;

        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Saving Contact..", false);
                }
            });

            try {
                id = ContactsController.saveContact(contact);
                if(id > 0){
                    contact.setId(id);
                    result = ContactsController.uploadImage(contact);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if(id == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Contact is not saved..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if(!result){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Image upload failed..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        populateList();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameTxt.getText().toString() + " has been added to your Contacts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }.start();
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if (resCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (reqCode == 1) {
             Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                photoTaken = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            contactImageimgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }
}

private void populateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
    contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    public ContactListAdapter() {
        super(ContactList.this, R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        final Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

        try {
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
            name.setText(currentContact.getName());
            TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());
            TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
            email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());
            TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cAddress);
            address.setText(currentContact.getAddress());
            TextView cPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cPriority);
            cPriority.setText(currentContact.getPriority());
            ImageView ivContactImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivContactImage);
            if(currentContact.getImage() != null)
                ivContactImage.setImageBitmap(currentContact.getImage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageView btnDeleteContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteContact);
        btnDeleteContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactList.this);
                builder.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        deleteContact(currentContact, ContactList.this);
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Contacts.size();
    }

    void deleteContact( final Contact contact, final Context context){
        new Thread(){
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            Boolean result = false;

            @Override
            public void run(){
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null, "Deleting Contact..", false);
                    }
                });

                try {
                    result = ContactsController.deleteContact(contact);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        if(!result){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Contact delete failed..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Contacts.remove(contact);
                            populateList();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), nameTxt.getText().toString() + " has been deleted from your Contacts!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android dial a phone number programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372561/android-dial-a-phone-number-programmatically)

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe That doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this code??

```
Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:123456789");
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Each contact has a different phone number, so I can't manually insert their phone number